# What happens if we fire a wooden bullet through a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, projectile

What happens to the bullet and the field if we fire a non-metallic (such as a wooden) bullet through the field beside a bar magnet in a vacuum?  Do the field lines move out of the way? Do the field lines retain the same shape inside the bullet as it passes through?  Do the electrons inside the bullet momentarily align with the field as the bullet passes?    The article [Fluidic Electrodynamics by Martins](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4611) says that fields act as an ideal fluid.  I'd like to understand how this functions when we are dealing with a non-conducting bullet.
[image: Magnetic Field]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wood has a relative magnetic permeability (the ratio of a medium's permeability with that of vacuum) of almost exactly 1. The magnetic field will be almost completely undisturbed.

Comment: So the lines would stay in position as the bullet passes.  Would this have any impact on the electrons within the wood?

Comment: @foolishmuse the wood frame will measure an electric field, hence an induced emf across its length. For suitably outlandish magnitude of $v × B$, you might induce dielectric breakdown, otherwise you can approximate the current through the (dry) wood by treating it as a conductor with a resistivity of about $10^{15} \Omega m$ - or save time and assume that $10^{15}$ is close enough to infinity not to worry about it.

Comment: For wet green wood, it might be worth doing the calculation, if you can get an estimate of the resistivity thereof.